# Write robot framework test case for search the search input keyword using below Web Elements?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I provided below HTML code snippets can you help me how to write a test case using html web element "searchInput".

This my HTML Elements:

```
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <input _ngcontent-c5="" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng touched" formcontrolname="searchInput" name="searchInput" placeholder="Please search here...?" type="text" ng-reflect-name="searchInput">
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="input-group-append">
    <button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn btn-bxc-black px-2"type="submit"> 
    <mat-icon _ngcontent-c5="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">search</mat-icon>
   </button></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${search_box}=   Get Element Attribute  css=[name="searchInput"]  value
```

or

```
${search_box}=   Get Element Attribute  css=[name="searchInput"]@value
```

have you tried this?
You need to import `selenium2Library` fir this.

Comment: Thanks!, How to use for this in seleniumLibrary?